# Migrating and developing content types

Tags: nodes, migrations

I have partially defined a complex content type on a remote site. It's not finished, by no means. Now, I want to migrate this content type to localhost so to continue my development locally. An obvious choice for exporting/importing data is Features. But - if I export the content type definition as a feature, will I be able then to develop it further on localhost? If not, what would be the right way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have no problem if you have the same field types installed on the localhost. For example If you are using the *email* field in your production site, it should be installed also in the localhost.

Assuming your are using Drupal 7, you have three choices:

- [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features)
- [Bundle copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy)

> Bundle copy is a replacement for the Content copy module which lives
>   in the CCK project for Drupal 6.

- [Field tools](http://drupal.org/project/field_tools)(currently alpha)

Comment: Here's a good overview of Features: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/drupal-features-module-101

Answer (score 0):

You must think carefully what dependencies your feature will have. How to structure the thing so it doesn't conflict with other Features.

Check the Kit is a specification:

http://drupal.org/project/kit